# Got this UnboundLocalError at /nesting/ local variable 'content' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to display the necessary field errors when the user who is populating the form does not enter valid information into the forms.

However, each I time I test the error script by clicking the submit button without populating any of the fields I get this error :

> UnboundLocalError at /nesting/ local variable 'content' referenced
>   before assignment

How do I correct this?

This is my code :

veiws.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from nesting.forms import Identity_form
from nesting.models import Identity_unique



class Identity_view(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'nesting/nesting.html'

    def get(self, request):

        form = Identity_form()

        Identities = Identity_unique.objects.filter(user = request.user)
        var = {'form': form, 'Identities': Identities}
        return render(request, self.template_name, var)

    def post(self, request):



        form  = Identity_form(request.POST or None)



        if form.is_valid():

            NIS = form.save(commit = False)
            NIS.user = request.user
            NIS.save()


            content = form.cleaned_data['NIS']

            form = Identity_form()


            return redirect('nesting:nesting')

        var = {'form': form, 'content': content}

        return render(request,self.template_name, var)
```

The error messages is saying the error is caused by this line

> ```
>         var = {'form': form, 'content': content}
> ```

```
        return render(request,self.template_name, var)
```

nesting.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}


<html>

    <head>

       {% block head %}

    <title>nesting</title>

    {% endblock %}

    </head>

    <body>

    {% block body %}


    <div class = "container"  style = "margin-top: 80px;">



              <form method = 'post' novalidate>

{% csrf_token %}

                {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
                  {{ hidden_field }}
                {% endfor %}


   <div class = "col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-6">

     <p class = "font-weight-bold">Create Patient</p>

                    {% if form.non_field_errors %}

                    <div class = "alert alert-danger" role = "alert">

                      {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}

                      {{ error }}

                      {% endfor %}

                    </div>

                    {% endif %}


  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}


          <div class = "form-group">

                       {% if form.is_bound %}
                               {% if field.errors %}
                                  {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
                                  {% for error in field.errors %}

                                  <div class = "invalid-feedback ">
                                    {{ error }}
                                  </div>

                                  {% endfor %}
                                {% else %}
                                    {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}

                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% else %}

                                    {% render_field field class="form-control" %}

                                    {% endif %}

                    {% if field.help_text %}
                    <small class = "form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
                    {% endif %}

          </div>
    {% endfor %}

  <button class = "btn-primary btn-large btn ">Submit</button>



</div>

                </form>

        </div>

         <div class = "col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

  {% for Identity in Identities %}


      <div class = "card" style = "margin-top: 40px;">



          <div class = "card-header">

            <p class="font-weight-bold"> {{Identity.First_Name}}  {{Identity.Last_Name}} </p>

          </div>

        <div class = "card-body">



            <div class = "card-title">
             <p class = "font-weight-light" style = "font-family: Optima">National Insurance Scheme : {{ Identity.NIS }}</p>
           </div>

             <p><small class = "card-text">Created On : {{ Identity.Timestamp }}</small></p>

             <p><small class = "card-text">Address : {{ Identity.Residence }}</small></p>



      </div>


  </div>
      {% endfor %}
</div>

  </div>

    {% endblock %}

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: The `var = {'form': form, 'content': content}` line you say the error is coming from doesn't actually seem to be anywhere in your code.

Comment: @user2357112 That line should be in the views.py document.

Comment: Please see [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

In your views. `content` is referenced in `var = {'form': form, 'content': content}`. It is only instantiated after `if form.is_valid()` block.

The unboundError occurs when your form is invalid, then the `var = {'form': form, 'content': content}` does not have any variable named `content` to refer to.

The Fix: instantiate `content` before the `if form.is_valid()` block.
`content = None`